# accessing variable of node into html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server, server-side

I have an **index.html** file and an app.js nodejs file. I have a var in app.js which is the name and want to print that variable in my index.html page

**Code**

```
var name = "Utsav";
var HTTP = require('HTTP');
var fs = require('fs');

function onRequest(req, res){
     fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Enter your request</title>
</head>
<body>
   <label for="Name:">Name</label><br>
   <input type="text" id="req"><br>
</body>
```

I want the value of name from app.js to print in a text box in index.html

Answer (score 1):

For displaying data in your index.html, you can pass it like this.

```
app.get('/profile', function(request, response) {
    response.render('pages/profile', {
        user : request.user
    });
})
```

and then in the html, you can view it like this.

```
<div>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <input type = "text" value = "<%= user.user.username %>" />
       </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: what is user  and user.user.username??

Comment: we are passing it as a json object. first user is the key. The rest is from the request.user obj. Its just an example. you can call your result obj in place of request.user and give it any key. In my case i gave it user.

Comment: @MrKhan This way of doing that you have mentioned resembles that of EJS templates, so essentially don't you have to mention your render engine as EJS for that? like `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`